# Read and write multiple files in R using loop

Tags: r, loops, file-io, string-formatting

```
  fn.cdrClusterAnalysis <- function(){
  #Data preprocessing
  cdrAcitivityInputDF <- fn.readCallDetailRecord("F:\\BE Project\\Telecom italia\\Full dataset\\November\\sms-call-internet-mi-2013-11-01.txt")
  cdrAcitivityInputDF <- fn.deriveAdditionalFields(cdrAcitivityInputDF)
  newdf = cdrAcitivityInputDF[, c(1,9,10,11,12)]


  newdf1 <-  ddply(newdf, .(square_id , activity_date , activity_hour), summarize, total_activity = sum(total_activity))

  write.csv(newdf1,file = "F:\\BE Project\\Code\\ProcessedDataset\\sms-call-internet-mi-2013-11-01.csv",row.names = FALSE)


}
```

I have 30 raw txt files(CDR data) for the month of november(1 file for 1 day) in a directory which I need to process and store the clean data in a separate folder. I don't want to run the code 30 times changing the day number, and I don't know how string formatting works in R. Can someone help me with this?

All files are stored in the same format, for example name of file of 16th day is "sms-call-internet-mi-2013-11-16.csv"

Files are read using `read.csv` in the function readCallDetailRecord.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop for `i` and in each case read

`paste0("F:\\BE Project\\Telecom italia\\Full dataset\\November\\sms-call-internet-mi-2013-11-",i,".txt")`

I had not considered that you have a `0` before single numbers. You can work around that by passing a conditional:

```
if (i<10){
paste0("F:\\BE Project\\Telecom italia\\Full dataset\\November\\sms-call-internet-mi-2013-11-0",i,".txt")
```

Full:

```
 fn.cdrClusterAnalysis <- function(day){
  if (day<10){
  day=paste0(0,day)
  }
  day=as.character(day)
  #Data preprocessing
  cdrAcitivityInputDF <- fn.readCallDetailRecord(paste0("F:\\BE Project\\Telecom italia\\Full dataset\\November\\sms-call-internet-mi-2013-11-",day,".txt"))
  cdrAcitivityInputDF <- fn.deriveAdditionalFields(cdrAcitivityInputDF)
  newdf = cdrAcitivityInputDF[, c(1,9,10,11,12)]


  newdf1 <-  ddply(newdf, .(square_id , activity_date , activity_hour), summarize, total_activity = sum(total_activity))

  write.csv(newdf1,file = paste0("F:\\BE Project\\Code\\ProcessedDataset\\sms-call-internet-mi-2013-11-",day,".csv"),row.names = FALSE)
}
for (day in 1:30){
    fn.cdrClusterAnalysis(day)
}
```